# How to start a Spring Batch step inside a ItemProcessor

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

Here is my scenario:

a1. read records from table A
a2. process these records one by one and generate a new temp table B for each record
b1. read records from table B, process these records data and save it in a file
a3. tag the record from table A as finished status

A pseudo code to describe this scenario:

```
  foreach item in items:
    1. select large amount data where id=item.id then save the result to temp table_id
    2. process all records in table_id then write then to a file
    3. update item status
    4. send message to client
```

This is my design:

1. create a Spring Batch job, set a date as its parameter
2. create a step1 to read records from table A
3. create a step2 to read records from temporary table B and start it in the processor of step1

I check the [Spring Batch docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/step.html#configureStep), I didn't find any related introduction about how to nest a step into a step's processor. seems the Step is the minimum unit in Spring Batch and it cannot be split.

**Update**

Here is the pseudo code about what I did now to solve the problem:
(I'm using spring boot 2.7.8)

```
def Job:
  PagingItemReader(id) :
    select date from temp_id
  FlatFileItemWriter:

application implement commandlinerunner:
  items = TableAReposiroy.SelectAllBetweenDate
  for item : items:
    Service.createTempTableBWithId(item.id)
    Service.loadDataToTempTable(item.id)

    job = createJob(item.id)
    luancher.run(job)
    
    update item status
```

Answer (score 0):

A step is part of a job. It is not possible to start a step from within an item processor.

You need to break your requirement into different steps, without trying to "nest" steps into each others. In your case, you can do something like:

1. create a Spring Batch job, set a date as its parameter
2. create a step1 to read records from table A and generate a new temp table B
3. create a step2 to read records from temporary table B, process these records data and save it in a file and tag the record from table A as finished status

The writer of step2 would be a composite writer: it writes data to the file AND updates the status of processed records in table A. This way, if there is an issue writing the file, the status of records in table A would be rolled back (in fact, they are not processed correctly as the write operation failed, in which case they need to be reprocessed).

Comment: thanks for your comment, since there're many records exist in table A and I need create a temp table for each of them, so here is my thought:
1. read records from table A base on a paging strategy
2. write a loop and create a job for each of the record, and pass the id of this record as the parameter to the job
3.1 in this job, add a listener to generate a temp table with a large amount of data based on the id param
3.2 paging item reader to reader records from temp table; flat file writer

Comment: I'm using spring boot application without any web server, and processing these jobs in sync mode is accept for me. Since there will be multi jobs been created with different name, I'm not sure if this is a good practice, appreciate if you can help me review this thought!

Comment: add a pseudo code to detail my question, i think the step 2 in code could be a job or step but as i mentioned above i didn't find how to execute a job or step inside a item processor of another job...

Comment: `I need create a temp table for each of them`: ah ok, that's a different story. Creating a table for each item is not a good idea. In this case, I believe 1, 2 and 3 could be in a single chunk-oriented step, following the driving query pattern (in which the reader reads items, the processor enriches items as needed and the writer writes both to the file and updates the status of items).

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, as i described in the pseudo code, there're two steps a and b, actually b is a substep of step a. seems SpringBatch doesn't support this scenario and finally i decide to split the whole process to multiple jobs and run them in a spring boot app, this should meets my needs. i'll do a further investigation later and update here. Anyway, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You should have single job with two steps, stepA and stepB, spring batch does provide provision for controlled flow of execution of steps, you can sequentially execute two steps. For each item Once stepA reaches its writer and writes data, stepB will start. You can configure stepB to read data written by stepA.

You can also pass data between steps using Job Execution context, Once stepA ends put data in Job Execution context, it can be accessed in stepB once it starts. This can help in your case because you can pass item identifier which stepA picked for processing and pass it to stepB  so that stepB can have this identifier in its writer to update its final status.